# A point moves along the curve

Tags: calculus

A point moves along the curve $3y + 4y^2 + 3x = 4$. When the point is at $(1, −1)$, its $x$-coordinate is increasing at the rate of $3$ units per second. How fast is its $y$-coordinate changing at that instant of time?

Comment: Use implicit differentiation. Time, denoted as $t$, is your implicit variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$3y + 4y^2 + 3x = 4 \tag{1}$

implies

$3y' + 8yy' + 3 = 0, \tag{2}$

or

$y' = -\dfrac{3}{8y + 3}; \tag{3}$

thus at the point $(1, -1)$ we have

$y'(1, -1) = \dfrac{3}{5}. \tag{4}$

If the motion of $x$ is given by some (differentiable) function $x(t)$, where $t$ is the time parameter, then by the chain rule we also have

$\dot y = \dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dt} = y'(x) \dot x(t), \tag{5}$

so at whatever time $t_0$ the point passes through $(1, -1)$ we have

$\dot y(t_0) = \dfrac{3}{5} \dot x(t_0) = \dfrac{3}{5} \times 3 ups = \dfrac{9}{5} ups, \tag{6}$

where "$ups$" abbreviates "units per second".

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as.always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3 $ at the point $(1, -1)$, the question is asking for $\frac{dy}{dt}$ .

let n' = $\frac{dn}{dt}$
$$3y + 4y^2 +3x = 4 $$
$$3y' + 8yy' + 3x' = 0$$
Then, plug in known values- $x'= 3 $ and $(1, -1)$.
$$ 3y' + 8(-1)y' + 3(3) = 0$$
Solve for $y'$.
$$-5y' = -9$$
$$y' = \frac{9}{5}$$
So $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{9}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides with respect to t: 3y' + 8yy' + 3x' = 0. Substituting x = 1, y = -1, and x' = 3 to solve for y': 3y' - 8y' + 9 = 0 ===> y' = 9/5 = 1.8 units/s.